# Prettier: Keep multiple arguments in decorator in the same line

Tags: typeorm, prettier

I recently upgraded from prettier@1.15.1 to prettier@1.19.1 and everything works great except for the following:

This line

```
@OneToMany(() => Address, address => address.contact, { cascade: true })
```

changed to this

```
@OneToMany(
    () => Address,
    address => address.contact,
    { cascade: true }
)
```

This really grinds my gears, has anyone an idea how to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the problem is already [solved](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/6953) and is released in 2.0.0.